# resources only loaded after page refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces, resources, wildfly-9

I'm facing some strange behaviour: In my webapp (JSF Mojarra with PrimeFaces 5 running on Wildfly 9) resources such as css and images are not loaded on the login page when someone first loads it. After refreshing it, all resources are there. Also, this happens every time you navigate there, e.g.:

1. navigate to login page (resources not loaded)
2. refresh page (resources loaded)
3. login and do whatever you wanna do on the webapp (resources loaded)
4. logout, which leads you to the login again (resources NOT loaded)

This only occured after I switched from Tomcat to Wildfly. Before, everything was fine. Any ideas? In case you need certain config files, let me know and I'll post them here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you cleared the cache? :)

Comment: That's definitely not the problem